# Openerp always goes to http instead of https with nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, odoo

I have openerp running on port 8069.
this is the nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    listen   [::]:80;
    listen   443 default ssl;
    server_name www.erp.mysite.hr;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/eco/erp_mysite_hr/erp_mysite_hr.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/eco/erp_mysite_hr/erp_mysite_hr.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 30m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
        rewrite ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}
```

aand location goes here and port proxy which works...

and when access openerp, always is http unless specified in the url with https, that way it works, but it is not redirected to https automatically.
this is the link that i get

```
http://erp.mysite.hr/web/login?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Ferp.mysite.hr%2Fweb
```

Any idea what could be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried doing 2 separate servers block? I mean, one for port 80 and another for port 443. Anything that goes to the port 80 one you redirect it to https://$host$request_uri; Can give you an example if you want.

Comment: yes i tried that, but seems like nothing affects the link, also tried with apache2 but it does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

This should work correctly, any http request will be redirected to https, which will be taken later by the top block.

```
server {
    listen   443 default ssl;
    server_name www.erp.mysite.hr;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/eco/erp_mysite_hr/erp_mysite_hr.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/eco/erp_mysite_hr/erp_mysite_hr.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 30m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    location / {
        #do whatever you need here
    }
}

server {
    listen  80;
    server_name www.erp.mysite.hr;
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks man, i also tried that too, but seems like openerp adds something, as stated in the questions, there is a redirect in the link and it is coming from somewhere

Comment: Try this and open the developer tools of the browser. If you see this 301 to https and then a http redirection, means that the erp is the one that makes the redirect. If you don't see this redirect, it means that something before nginx is the one doing it. Knowing your stack we can begin to work on where or who is actually doing the wrong redirect. Are you passing the right parameters headers for the stack to know it's https?

Comment: here is the problem:
Result

https://erp.ecomobile.hr
303 SEE OTHER
https://erp.ecomobile.hr/web
200 OK
/web/login?redirect=
Javascript Location Refresh
Problems found:

    Javascript Redirect.

Comment: so now who is doing the redirect? ::D its the erp somehow

Answer (score 0):

First. Change your nginx code, second go to system parameters and change a parameter

```
web.base.url = "https://erp.mysite.hr"
```

to your url.

You can also add a parameter url freeze to prevent reloading of this attribute

```
web.base.url.freeze = True
```